# How to set label color with setCustomProperty in QGIS2?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

I can set most font properties like this:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Noto Sans")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/isExpression", True)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "title")    
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "0")
```

But not font color. I've tried various ways of specifying the color:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontColor", "red")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontColor", "#ff0000")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontColor", QColor(255,0,0,255)
```

Surely there is a custom property for font color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the value for the red (**R**), green (**G**), blue (**B**) and alpha (**A**) parameters which are stored in the `textColor` property:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/textColorR", 255)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/textColorG", 0)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/textColorB", 0)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/textColorA", 255)
```

Comment: Is it possible to define an expression in setCustomProperty for textColor??? @Joseph

Comment: @ChetanVashisth - Have a look at this question about setting custom properties: [Setting a Background Color with RVBT field with python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326388/setting-a-background-color-with-rvbt-field-with-python). If you still need help, I would suggest you ask a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Dhanyawad @Joseph Bhaiya :)(Thanks in Hindi)